# Web scraping with R and phantomjs using a small js script returning error

Tags: javascript, r, phantomjs

I need to get the content from this page containing some scripts:
https://grouper.swissdrg.org/swissdrg/single?version=7.3&pc=1337_70_0_0_M_11_00_15_0_2018/08/07_2018/08/22_C18.4_C07_-_45.81.11$$&provider=acute&locale=de. 
For other pages containing js its working fine but not for the one I need.

phantomjs.exe is in the root directoy and successfully invoked by a system call (win7 64 bit):

system("phantomjs WebScrapeV1.js")

The java script file WebScrapeV1.js is as follows:

```
var url ='https://grouper.swissdrg.org/swissdrg/single?version=7.3&pc=1337_70_0_0_M_11_00_15_0_2018/08/07_2018/08/22_C18.4_C07_-_45.81.11$$&provider=acute&locale=de';
var page = new WebPage()
var fs = require('fs');
page.open(url, function (status) {
  just_wait();
});
function just_wait() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fs.write('WebScrapeV1.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
  }, 2500);
}
```

This is the error I get:

Error: [mobx.array] Index out of bounds, function (t) {return{key:t.version,text:t["name_"+e.root.navigation.lang],value:t.version}} is larger than 30

https://grouper.swissdrg.org/packs/App-3dd15966701d9f6fd4db.js:1 in br
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'n.push(this.pdx)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A longer timeout may be what you need. I had to use 3600 to get all the contents (that site was super super slow for me). Here's a way you can modify the timeout in the event of errors without having to hand-modify a phantomjs script.

First, we'll make a function to wrap up all the complexity:

```
#' Read contents from a URL with phantomjs
#' 
#' @param url the URL to scrape
#' @param timeout how long to wait, default is `2500` (ms)
#' @param .verbose, if `TRUE` (the default), display the generated 
#'        scraping script and any `stdout` output from phantomjs
read_phantom <- function(url, timeout=2500, .verbose = TRUE) {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require("glue", character.only = TRUE, quiet=TRUE)
    require("crayon", character.only = TRUE, quiet=TRUE)
  })

  phantom_template <- "
var url = {url};
var page = new WebPage()
var fs = require('fs');
page.open(url, function (status) {{
  just_wait();
});
function just_wait() {{
  setTimeout(function() {{
    fs.write({output_file}, page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
  }, {timeout});
}
" 

  url <- shQuote(url)

  phantom_bin <- Sys.which("phantomjs")

  tf_in <- tempfile(fileext = ".js")
  on.exit(unlink(tf_in), add=TRUE)

  tf_out <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  on.exit(unlink(tf_out), add=TRUE)

  output_file <- shQuote(tf_out)

  phantom_script <- glue(phantom_template)

  if (.verbose) {
    cat(
      crayon::white("Using the following generated scraping script:\n"),
      crayon::green(phantom_script), "\n", sep=""
    )
  }

  writeLines(phantom_script, tf_in)

  system2(
    command = phantom_bin, 
    args = tf_in,
    stdout = if (.verbose) "" else NULL
  )

  paste0(readLines(tf_out, warn = FALSE), collapse="\n")

}
```

Now, we'll use your URL with a longer timeout:

```
read_phantom(
  url = "https://grouper.swissdrg.org/swissdrg/single?version=7.3&pc=1337_70_0_0_M_11_00_15_0_2018/08/07_2018/08/22_C18.4_C07_-_45.81.11$$&provider=acute&locale=de",
  timeout = 3600
) -> doc

substr(doc, 1, 100)
## [1] "<html><head>\n<script src=\"https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1071.min.js\"></script><script type=\" text"

nchar(doc)
## [1] 26858
```

Note that phantomjs is considered a legacy tool as the main developers have moved on since headless Chrome came on the scene. Unfortunately, there's no way to set a timeout for headless Chrome in the simple cmd line interface to it so you're kinda stuck with phantomjs for now.

I'd suggest trying [`splashr`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) but you're on Windows and `splashr` requires Docker; alternatively, [`decapitated`](http://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/decapitated) has an orchestration counterpart [`gepetto`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/gepetto) but that requires nodejs; either of those combos seem to be a painful for may folks to get working on that legacy operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort. Have tried the function an different Win 7 PC. Unfortunately, I still always get the same errors  as described above. Probably your are using a linux OS?

Comment: I fired up my Win 7 VM and sure enough phantomjs tosses similar errors which likely means it was compiled with some implicit limits due to the crippled nature of Windows (the `V8` package has similar issues with the DLL it uses on Windows for the js vm).

Comment: Just tried it with headless chrome on windows and without the ability to specify a longer timeout it truncates the HTML output there.

Comment: The solution above seem to be valid for non-Win OS only

Comment: Mostly b/c phantomjs is crippled on that rly bad OS.